# Como usar Distinct reduciendolo a una columna, no todas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy consultando una tabla que devuelve numID y fechaProc.

```
SELECT distinct numID,fechaProc FROM procedimientos
```

Aun así me salen repetidas numID

```
1098651104  2020-02-19 02:01:21
1056613369  2020-02-10 02:49:30
1018488195  2020-02-19 11:57:35
1018455309  2020-03-06 06:52:09
1018455309  2020-03-06 04:24:24
1018455309  2020-03-06 06:36:39
```

Necesito que solo me elimine repetidos en numID. Necesito que devuelva el siguiente resultado:

```
    1098651104  2020-02-19 02:01:21
    1056613369  2020-02-10 02:49:30
    1018488195  2020-02-19 11:57:35
    1018455309  2020-03-06 06:52:09
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes proceder de ese modo:

- Obtén el máximo de la fecha
- Realiza el agrupamiento por el valor de la columna de la cual tratas de obtener el valor con `DISTINCT`
- Hacemos uso de la función de agregación `MAX` para que de este modo de los 3 valores que tienen el mismo `ID` solo se considere el del valor máximo y queden descartados los demás

Tu consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT DISTINCT numID, 
       MAX(fecha_proc)
FROM procedimientos
GROUP BY numID;
```

Dando un resultado como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sos el mejor, muchas gracias

Comment: Amigo, esta solución me sirvió en la version 5.5.24 de MYSQL, sin embargo cuando la hago en 8.0.19 me sale error relacionado con el group by Error code 1055

Comment: No veo por que te debería fallar, de hecho tengo la misma versión que tu 8.x